# Is this possible to reset a SAP R/3 installation process?

Tags: sap-basis, sap-r3

As part of a testing process I finished the installation in "System Copy" mode of a SAP 46C SR2 system under Solaris/Oracle. Database already has data.

Something was wrong in the installation although it finished without troubles, so I need to begin all the installation process again without having to re-install the database and Operating system.

Is it possible to do this? If yes, which folders/directories should I delete? Which other thing should I consider?

Comment: Hi Tristan
Consider asking this question on Serverfault as well, as the Basis folk my be hanging out there.  Here's to hoping the SAP community grows a bit on Stackoverflow & Serverfault etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. But I didn't do it on solaris. The installation manual has a section on "deletion of sap system installation". Because you have finish the installation, you have to delete the system you have installed. And when you will run the procees again, it will be a new installation. BTW as long that you have a working db you don't have to worry about much. You can even just copy installation from another server. Adapt few profile files, and environment variables and you will have a working system.